# Kingfisher image loading error

Tags: ios, swift, caching, kingfisher

I have a problem I hope you can help solve. I am using Kingfisher in my app, and it is wonderful. In my main user search tableview, it loads and caches images perfectly. But oddly when I try to cache images in another tableview, where the images are larger width and height size, it does not load them. Weirdly it only loads one image or two only usually. Now I thought this had to do with the size of the image, but I don't really thing so. Here is some code to show I am download and storing the image in firebase

```
  let storage = Storage.storage().reference().child(uid).child("userPhoto.jpg")
            if let uploadData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(photo, 0.2) {
                storage.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion:
                    { (metadata, error) in
                        if error != nil {
                            print(error!)
                            return
                        }
                        if let imagerUrl = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString {
                            let ref = Database.database().reference()
                            let randomString =  NSUUID().uuidString

                            print(randomString)
                            let postFeed = [randomString : imagerUrl]
                            print(self.photos)
                            self.collectionerView.reloadData()
                            self.activityer.stopAnimating()
                           ref.child("users").child(uid).child("profilePhotos").updateChildValues(postFeed)
                        }
                })
            }
```

A now for how I am loading/fetching the urls into an array. The height and width of the imageView = 150 * 150

```
func grabPhotos (uid: String) {
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref.child("users").child(uid).child("profilePhotos").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in
        if let theirPhotos = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
            for (_,one) in theirPhotos {
                let newPhoto = Photo()
                newPhoto.photoUrl = one as? String
                print(one as! String)
                self.imagers.append(newPhoto)
            }
            self.tablerView.reloadData()

        } else {
            self.activityer.stopAnimating()
        }

    }, withCancel: nil)
}
```

And lastly the caching the image

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tablerView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "userImagers", for: indexPath) as! UsersImagersTableViewCell
    if let imagerl = self.imagers[indexPath.row].photoUrl {
        let urler = URL(string: imagerl)
        cell.imagerView.kf.setImage(with: urler)
    } else {
        cell.imagerView.image = UIImage(named: "profiler")
    }
    return cell
}
```

So to sum it up, some images load, while others don't though I download and store them the same way. I would like to find a solution to this, so if you have one, please respond. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to cache them in a folder created in Documents like this

1- put this code in viewDidLoad

```
 documentsUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0])

    var logsPath = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent("Logs")

    do {
        try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: logsPath!, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)


        var res = URLResourceValues()

        res.isExcludedFromBackup = true

        try logsPath?.setResourceValues(res)


        print("Created")
    } catch let error as NSError {
        NSLog("failed100 \(error.debugDescription)")
    }
```

2-

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = areaSettTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:CellIdentifier1) as! logTableViewCell

    let tr = allTrips[indexPath.row]

 let imgPath =  documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent("\(tr.tripId).jpg")

    print("qwqwqw \((imgPath?.path)!)")

    if(FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath:(imgPath?.path)!))
    {

        do
        {
            if let data:Data? = try Data.init(contentsOf:imgPath!)
            {
                cell.mapImageV.image=UIImage.init(data:data!)

                cell.imgActivity.isHidden = true
            }


        } catch let error as NSError {
            NSLog("failed1150 \(error.debugDescription)")
        }
    }
    else
    {

        if(tr.img != "nil" && tr.img != "")
        {


             cell.imgActivity.isHidden = false

            cell.imgActivity.startAnimating()

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            print("This is run on the background queue")

            let url = NSURL(string:tr.img) // myurl is the webpage address.

            let data = NSData(contentsOf:url! as URL)



            let imgIn =  documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent("\(tr.tripId).jpg")

            DispatchQueue.main.async
            {
                print("This is run on the main queue, after the previous code in outer block")

                if !( data == nil )
                {

                    data?.write(to:imgIn!, atomically: true)

                    self.areaSettTable.reloadData()



                }
                else
                {
                    print("nillll data . . .")
                }
            }


        }

        }

        else
            {
                cell.imgActivity.isHidden = true


            }




    }


return cell



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably one of the stupidest mistakes I have ever made in programming. I accidentally copied an pasted the code for saving a profile image to saving multiple images. Well in order to store those images and reference them, they need different keys. If you look at my code above, they are not individual, this is why it kept only downloading one image. Solved it by doing

```
 let storage = Storage.storage().reference().child(uid).child("userPhotos").child("photo\(key)")
```

3 hours wasted, whatever lol